# Selenium IDE - stop if a specific string was found

Tags: selenium-ide

Is there a way to tell selenium IDE to stop if a specific text on a page was found?

For example if a page contains some MySQL / php Errors I want to get notified. (I would check for partial mysql strings like "near * at line")

What I use now is assertText, but this continues the test if the text is available. Is there some negation like NOT assertText.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript evaluation and "!" (javascript -not- expression)

```
storeElementPresent | //*[contains(text(),"searchedText")] | searchedTextpresent
verifyEval          | !storedVars['searchedTextpresent']    | true
```

additionally you can collect more variables and combine the verifyEval part into logical expression using "&&" and "|" (javascript and and or)

```
storeElementPresent | //*[contains(text(),"searchedText1")] | searchedText1present
storeElementPresent | //*[contains(text(),"searchedText2")] | searchedText2present
verifyEval          | !storedVars['searchedText1present'] && !!storedVars['searchedText2present'] | true
```